# Can a familiar be resummoned on the other side of a door?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, targeting, familiars, summoning

There is a thread about Conjure Elemental not being able to be cast on the other side of a wall due to targeting rules. Does this also apply to bringing a familiar from its extradimensional space? Or can the familiar basically pop up behind a door and unlock it for you since it is within 30 feet?